# How to connect FLIR thermal camera to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, kernel-modules, camera

I've been trying to connect a FLIR thermal camera to my Raspberry Pi for the past three days. The code is being provided by the manufacturer and can be found [here](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/tree/master/software/v4l2lepton).

I've downloaded the kernel and installed it. I also cloned the v4l2loopback repo, compiled it and copied the `.ko` file into the correct directory. I even manged to run the `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback` command and it went off without a hitch.

However, when I get to the final step and attempt to run the command `./v4l2lepton /dev/videoX` I get this error: `Failed to open v4l2sink device. (No such file or directory)`

I have no idea what file they are saying is missing.

I also ran `ls -hl /dev/video*` it just told me that it couldn't access it because there is not such file or directory. This confuses me because the instructions didn't talk about having to set-up any kind of directory like this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are connecting the *Flir ONE* via USB, but the code seems to access the *Lepton* *module* inside the device vie SPI and/or I2C. Their readme says:

> with the Lepton + basic breakout board.

---

It seems there is a way to use it via USB:

- http://www.eevblog.com/forum/thermal-imaging/flir-one-thermal-imaging-camera-teardown-and-hacks/
- http://www.eevblog.com/forum/thermal-imaging/question-about-flir-one-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code this error is caused when trying to open a file (probably not an ordinary file, but a device). In variable `v4l2dev`, this variable is initilized to `/dev/video1`, but is over written by `argv[1]`. When you ran the program you used `/dev/videoX`. It is saying that `/dev/videoX` does not exist.

I imagine that the docs intend you to replace the X with a number, but were not clear on this.

Have a look for what devices exist: `ls -hl /dev/video*`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but when I ran `ls -hl /dev/video*` it just told me that it couldn't access it because there is not such file or directory. This confuses me because the instructions didn't talk about having to set-up any kind of directory like this.

Comment: Add this info to your question; sorry I do not know. Hope someone else does, but make it easy for them by putting all relevant info into question.